# How to use beautiful soup to get elements that contain/do not contain specific classes

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to get a table and save it to Excel with pyhon scripts. Here is the response:

```
<body>
<table id="need">
<tr height="30" align="center">
<td>need</td>
<td id="td1">need</td>
<td id="td2" type="wholeLast">not need</td>
<td id="td3" type="whole">need</td>
...
</tr>
<tr height="30" align="center" cid="2" class="txt">
<td>not need</td>
<td id="td1">not need</td>
<td id="td2" type="wholeLast">not need</td>
<td id="td3" type="whole">not need</td>
...
</tr>
...
</table>
<table>
...
</table>
</body>
```

I need to get the contents in `<tr>` except `<tr>` with 'class="txt"' and the `<td>` except `<td>` with 'type="wholeLast"'. In short, I need to get all the "need" in the above response.

I tried this:`trs = soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"height": "30", "align": "center"})`. But I don't know how to remove the `<td>` which type="wholeLast". Maybe I need to use other ways.

Any suggestion is appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with css selectors and `not` pseudo class you could do this

```
tds=soup.select('tr:not(.txt) td:not([type="wholeLast"])')
```

Comment: Generally agree - Think you could pop the `td` in `:not()` pseudo class `soup.select('tr:not(.txt) td:not([type="wholeLast"])')`